# Some LaTeX symbols are not supported

Tags: bug, mathjax

On [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), the editor doesn’t recognize `$\odiv$`? But it is in [the Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://zelmanov.ptep-online.com/ctan/symbols-a4.pdf)
. How can I use it?

Comment: MathJax emulates some LaTeX commands but not all of them. See the [list of commands](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands) supported by MathJax. It contains `\oslash` but not  `\odiv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implemented LaTeX environment only supports commands usually supplied by standard packages, and `mathabx` (which supplies ⨸) is not one of them. It does however support Unicode input.

Thus you either have to resort to `\oslash` or similar or use the corresponding Unicode character (⨸), which will however be rendered differently than the more common encircled symbols like `\oplus` and will not be rendered at all on some machines.

Comment: The character is a white box for me on this computer (not surprising).

Comment: @WeaponofChoice: Also in MathJax rendering? I.e., if you go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and put $⨸$ in the field, do you still get a box in the preview rendering?

Comment: Yes, same blank space. I know this is a localized font issue (I saw the symbol on another computer). Just pointing out a pitfall of Unicode solution.

Comment: @WeaponofChoice: … and rightly so. I added this to my answer.